# Readable display (IB) names for custom attributes

Tags: swift, interface-builder

Some attributes of standard macOS/iOS classes appear in IB with names, containing spaces, e.g 'Line Break', 'Text Direction'. Also some names repeat, like 'Title' - 'Alternate', 'Image' - 'Alternate' for NSButton.

Can I specify a display name, different from variable name, for a custom attribute? If I just place @IBInspectable, the display name is always a property name with first letter capitalised.

Update: Underscores are converted to spaces. Also a capital letter produces a space before it. For example, `myItem` or `my_Item` appear in IB as 'My Item'. However I am interested in general.

Comment: There isn't any supported way. You could make a _different_ property be `@IBInspectable` and have it be a computed property façade for the real property. Skanky, but better than nothing.

Comment: matt: As as far as I understand you, this doesn't help to replicate names. For example, NSButton has names "Image and "Image Alternate" the second appearing in IB as "Alternate". I want to introduce properties "Background" and "Background Alternate", so that the second also appear in IB as "Alternate", otherwise in IB they both look like "Background ...". Standard UI have this feature.

Comment: "I want to introduce properties "Background" and "Background Alternate"" Yes, that's just what I am saying you can do. Of course a property could never be called Background Alternate with a space, so that that example is totally artificial. If you give me a _real_ example I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: matt: Of course, the property will be called backgroundAlternative, but since IB doesn't wrap, only truncates the titles with elipsis, it will list it as "Background...".  For system UI items, like NSButton  property 'alternateImage' appears just as Alternate.

Comment: Okay, I'll illustrate what I mean, since you don't seem to be getting it from my description.

Answer (score 0):

Use a facade computed property with the desired name as the `IBDesignable` property, like this:

```
class MyView : UIView {
    @IBInspectable var background : String = ""
    var backgroundAlternate : String = ""
    @IBInspectable var alternate : String {
        get {
            return backgroundAlternate
        }
        set {
            backgroundAlternate = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

When you enter a value into the Alternate field in the attributes inspector, that value is routed into the `backgroundAlternate` property.

Comment: It was already discussed in previous comments. The façade technique can be used only once in a class. Meanwhile standard NSButton has two properties: alternateImage and alternateTitle both appearing as 'Alternate' in IB list. As far as I can see, this cannot be replicated with a custom view. Also I wonder if it is safe to have 'aternate' property  while overriding NSButton, since it may be used internally.

Comment: Well, it sounds like it falls into the category of stuff Apple can do and we can't.